# Log4j 2 - display log from running application

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using Log4j 2 and would like to be able to connect to my running application and view its logging output. I have come across the JMX GUI client and StatusLogger but that only seems able to display the logging from Log4j itself and not the applications output. I have looked at all the Appenders and I cannot find one with this capability.

Is it possible to configure StatusLogger in some way to capture application logging or is there a different approach?

Comment: Have a look at graylog2 with gelf appender. With gelf appender you can send your logs over network and manage them using graylog2.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no GuiAppender or similar. I can think of two ways to accomplish this. One is to simply tail the log file in your application.

The other one is to build a custom appender that append log events to a memory buffer. The log4j-core module, under src/test has a org.apache.logging.log4j.test.appender.ListAppender intended for JUnit tests that may be a good starting point. (You'll need to be careful about running out of memory of course.)